# How to make a private static property in javascript es6?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to make a function that is both private and static in javascript. Is there a way to do it?

I know by doing

```
#myfunc = function() {

}
```

I can make it private. But when I try to access that from a function marked as static, I get

(node:15092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read private member #myfunc from an object whose class did not declare it

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't define private static methods with the current ecmascript version. But you can emulate an static method by declaring a function outside the class but within the same file.

While you don't export that function from that file, it will work the same way as a private static method, but the way of calling it.

It's a way to achieve the same behaviour with the current javascript specification.

```
// MyFile.js

function myPrivateMethod() {} // You won't have access to this function outside this file

export class MyClass {
   myMethod() {
     myPrivateMethod();
   }
}
```

If you want to access static properties, you just need to call MyClass.myStaticProperty. In that case I suggest you to define the function after the class definition, to avoid hoisting issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make static property private, or other accessibility. Because, it's by default public and it's always true

> It is not possible to specify the accessibility of statics—they are effectively always public.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking to make a function that is both private and static in JavaScript.

That's not possible, because static properties are properties in the class object (the one you call with `new`). So if someone has access to the class object, they'll have access to any static properties.

You can, however, use a regular function to replace it. You can even create a object that contains the private "static" functions and call them from that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply simulate private static properties by embedding the class definition in a function and use and declare your private static properties using the let statement before you declare your class. These variables will be visible in your class but nowhere else.

```
     let _myPrivate = 123;  // variable exist the whole lifetime of the page.
     MyClass = class {
       get myPrivate() { return _myPrivate; }     // returns 123
     }
```